# Highlight a date range if it contains today's date

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have start dates in column N, and end dates in column O - is there any way I can highlight them if the range contains the current date?

eg if today's date in 08/05/2019, the start date is 06/05/2019 in N, and end date is 12/05/2019 in O it should highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as follow:

Sample data:

[image]

Select column N:O and add new conditional formatting rule, use a formula:

```
=AND(TODAY()>=$O1,TODAY()<=$P1)
```

Choose your fill and click OK.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I couldn't work it our for the life of me!